# django-rest-framework id field in user serializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have project with api on drf

My User Model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    first_name = models.CharField(
        'Имя',
        max_length=150,
    )
    last_name = models.CharField(
        'Фамилия',
        max_length=150
    )
    image = ResizedImageField(size=[255, 260],
                              upload_to='image/',
                              quality=51)
    role = models.CharField(
        'Роль в проекте',
        max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(
        'Описание',
        blank=True,
        null=True
    )

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Пользователь'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Пользователи'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.first_name
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'image',
                  'role', 'description')
        read_only_fields = ['id']
```

views.py

```
class UserViewSet(GetListRetrieveMixin):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    pagination_class = None
    filter_backends = (SearchFilter,)
    search_fields = ('id',)
    filterset_fields = ['id', ]
    filter_fields = ('id',)
```

Now i have this json without id field

[
{
"first_name": "testname",
"last_name": "testsurname",
"image": "http://example.com/media/image/test.jpeg",
"role": "test role",
"description": "test desc"
},

but i need this

[
{
"id": "1"
"first_name": "testname",
"last_name": "testsurname",
"image": "http://example.com/media/image/test.jpeg",
"role": "test role",
"description": "test desc"
},

What i tried to do:

Add id in serializer Class like that:

class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
id = serializers.IntegerField(read_only=True)
class Meta:
model = Foo
fields = '**all**'

But i cant resolve my problem